# Finding the sum $\sum_{i<j}z_iz_j$ where {$ z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_7$} are the vertices of a regular heptagon.

Tags: complex-analysis, contest-math

This is a PhD entrance question from TIFR 2020.
A regular heptagon is given and the points $z_1,...,z_7$ are vertices of unit modulus. For evaluating the sum I tried to use the exponential representation for the vertices but the condition $i<j$ is causing trouble. Can someone provide me some hint?

Comment: You can consider $\sum_{i \ne j} z_iz_j= 2\times \sum_{i<j} z_iz_j$.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{i<j}z_iz_j=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_i z_i\right)^2-\sum_i z_i^2\right]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $e^{2\pi i/7}=:\omega$, and choose an $\alpha\in{\mathbb R}$ such that $$z_j=e^{i\alpha}\>\omega^j \qquad(0\leq j\leq6)\ .$$
You then have
$$\sum_{j<k}z_j z_k={e^{2i\alpha}\over2}\left(2\sum_{j<k}\omega^j\>\omega^k\right)={e^{2i\alpha}\over2}\left(\left(\sum_{j=0}^6\omega^j\right)^2-\sum_{j=0}^6 \omega^{2j}\right)=0\ ,$$
because $\sum_{j=0}^6\omega^j=0$ and  $\{1,\omega^2,\omega^4,\ldots,\omega^{12}\}=\{1,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots,\omega^6\}$.